# Substract rows by sums of other rows based on condition

Tags: r

I have following dataframe:

```
a = data.frame("ID"=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,5,5,5,5),
                "Year"=c(2016,2017,2016,2017,2016,2017,2017,2017,2016,2017),
                "Quarter"=c(1,1,2,2,3,3,1,2,3,3),
                "Revenue" = c(100,300,200,600,500,700,200,300,800,900))


   ID Year Quarter Revenue
1   1 2016       1     100
2   1 2017       1     300
3   1 2016       2     200
4   1 2017       2     600
5   1 2016       3     500
6   1 2017       3     700
7   5 2017       1     200
8   5 2017       2     300
9   5 2016       3     800
10  5 2017       3     900
```

I want to subtract the revenues of the preceding quarters for each quarter for each ID. The revenue of the 2. quarter gets substracted by the revenue of the 1. quarter, the revenue of the 3. quarter gets substracted by the sum of the 1. and 2. quarter, etc.. So this would mean for example for ID=1, year=2016:

2016 Q1 = 100, 2016 Q2 = 100 (200-100), 2016 Q3 = 300 (500-100-100).

There are also some ID's that dont have data for some quarters, like ID=5, year=2016, who only has data for the 3. quarter, so imaginary 0's could be substracted and we would get 2016 Q3 = 800 (800-0-0).

The desired output should look like this:

```
   ID Year Quarter Revenue
1   1 2016       1     100
2   1 2017       1     300
3   1 2016       2     100
4   1 2017       2     300
5   1 2016       3     300
6   1 2017       3     100
7   5 2017       1     200
8   5 2017       2     100
9   5 2016       3     800
10  5 2017       3     600
```

Is there a simple way to do this or do I need to write a function for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)

a %>%
   left_join(mutate(a, Quarter = Quarter + 1),
             by= c("ID", "Year", "Quarter"))%>%
   mutate(Revenue = Revenue.x - coalesce(Revenue.y,0)) %>%
   select(-contains("."))
   ID Year Quarter Revenue
1   1 2016       1     100
2   1 2017       1     300
3   1 2016       2     100
4   1 2017       2     300
5   1 2016       3     300
6   1 2017       3     100
7   5 2017       1     200
8   5 2017       2     100
9   5 2016       3     800
10  5 2017       3     600
```

Comment: I tried with a %>% arrange(ID, Year, Quarter) %>% group_by(ID, Year) %>% mutate(Revenue = case_when(row_number() == 1 ~ Revenue,
                                                        row_number() == 2 ~ Revenue[2] - Revenue[1],
                                                        TRUE ~ Revenue[3] - Revenue[2] - Revenue[1]))
I used that vector index approax before, but it's not working here, doesn't group by arrange values by default. Just to make sure, I even added arrange function, still it doesn't work. Can you please help me understand why.

Comment: @KarthikS First, you cannot `case_when` in this case. Second, `arrange` doesnot in any way help. Probably you are thinking of `group_by`. Lastly, what are you trying to do? I do not understand what you are doing

Comment: What I am trying to do is if we get arrange the dataframe using a %>% arrange(ID, Year, Quarter), we have Revenue for each Year with Quarters 1 to 3. With, case_when I tried do subract first quarter from second and first and second quarters from the third based on the row numbers. Could you please let me know why case_when will not work in such cases.

Comment: @KarthikS DOes the solution I provided above not satisfactory? Note that you could have data for quarter 3 and 1 with no quarter 2. according to the arrangement, you will subtract 3 and 1 but you should not do that. Just try to understand the solution provided.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `purrr`'s `accumulate` function to perform such recursive calculation.

```
library(dplyr)
a %>%
  group_by(ID, Year) %>%
  mutate(Revenue = Revenue - cumsum(purrr::accumulate(lag(Revenue)[-1], 
                                    ~.y - .x, .init = 0)))

#      ID  Year Quarter Revenue
#   <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1     1  2016       1     100
# 2     1  2017       1     300
# 3     1  2016       2     100
# 4     1  2017       2     300
# 5     1  2016       3     300
# 6     1  2017       3     100
# 7     5  2017       1     200
# 8     5  2017       2     100
# 9     5  2016       3     800
#10     5  2017       3     600
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in `data.table`.

```
library(data.table)

setDT(a)

a[,Revenue:= Revenue-shift(Revenue,type = 'lag',fill = 0), by= c('ID','Year')]
```